# Perl detached CLI exe that can be monitored

Tags: windows, perl, process

On a Windows XP PC, I would like to have a perl script that can start a number detatched CLI exe processes in their own windows. The script would then be able to monitor the PIDs, for example, to determine when the detached process has finished. I have tried a number of ideas but none will give me the new window. System (start...) I am unable to monitor the new process. Win32:process I am unable to get a new window for the CLI exe I wish to run. I am guessing I am missing a trick here.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` to `Win32::Process::CreateProcess`

- [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess)
- [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Process Creation Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This was my first try. I got no new window and all output from the dos exe went to the window the perl scrip was run from.

Comment: If it helps this is one veriation I have used: Win32::Process::Create($proc,
         "C:\\Program Files\\WinFF\\ffmpeg.exe",
         'ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp3 -vn -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 64k -ac 2 -ar 22050 temp.m4a', 1, 
      CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, ".") ||  die Win32::FormatMessage(Win32::GetLastError());

Comment: Did you actually import the constant? (You use `use strict; use warnings;`, right?)

Comment: This is my test script:

use Win32::Process qw(STILL_ACTIVE);
use Win32;

my $proc = "";
my $exitcode;

      
Win32::Process::Create($proc,
   "C:\\Program Files\\WinFF\\ffmpeg.exe",
   'ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp3 -vn -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 64k -ac 2 -ar 22050 temp.m4a', 1, 
   CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, ".") ||  die Win32::FormatMessage(Win32::GetLastError());
        
$proc->GetExitCode( $exitcode );

while ($exitcode == 259){
 sleep (1);
 $proc->GetExitCode( $exitcode );
 }


print "Finished\n";

Comment: So no to both of my questions. Turn them into yeses. Start by adding `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Don't you think that would have been more readable if you had added it to your question?

Comment: OK, So now I get the following error message. A quick google of this error does not bring much up for windows. At this point I am running Strawberry Perl. 

Bareword "CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at test.pl line 10.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: update non of the constants are being exsported it would appear. If I had code 0x00000010 for the flag it all works but this is less than ideal. How can I get the constants exported? I assumed this would happen automatically. I have tried a manual exsport with the STILL_ACTIVE constant but that has not worked either.

Comment: It's normally exported, but you overrode the default list when you asked tthat STILL_ACTIVE and only `STILL_ACTIVE` be exported. `use Win32::Process qw( STILL_ACTIVE CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE );`